# Magento removing cart item redirects to homepage

Tags: php, magento-1.9, http-status-code-302

I have this site where there are two stores German and English(Default).

On German store, It is getting translated from the 3rd party through a proxy pass.

Everything is working great on default store. But on German store, if the item is removed from cart it is redirecting to homepage.

FYI I have kept SID enabled.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to ask a question and describe your ploblem a little more. And add some code!

Comment: The error is not related with code, it is associated with core functionality of the magento

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

While removing an item from shopping cart, redirecting to homepage not to the check out page

### Solution:

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`

In the above php file find the function

```
public function deleteAction(){
  // code here 
}
```

Replace

```
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
```

with

`$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`

Now check the checkout page, no redirection to homepage.

Comment: I dont want to override the controller, the website is getting translated from third party after that only it is causing this error